# MySQL delete query in PHP doesn't work in IF statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I made a script which inserts a row from one table in another, but then it has to delete the record from one table. For some reason that isn't working. Could someone please help me out with this?

My code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css"/>
        <?php session_start();
           if(!isset($_SESSION['login_id'])){
           $url = 'helpdesklogin.php';
           header("Location: $url");
            }
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $server="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $connect_mysql=mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die ("Connection Failed!");
    $mysql_db=mysql_select_db("helpdesk_middenpolder",$connect_mysql) or die ("Could not Connect to Database");
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO afgehandelden_incidenten SELECT * FROM incidenten WHERE incidentID='$id'");
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    if($result=mysql_query($query)){
        $query2=mysql_query("DELETE FROM incidenten WHERE incidentID=$id");
    }
    else {
    echo mysql_error();
    }

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use pdo instead of mysql_ functions

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan His question is still valid you cannot simply mark it down because you prefer pdo instead of mysql. I know its deprecated but he didn't ask advice on which method to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong way:

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO afgehandelden_incidenten SELECT * FROM incidenten WHERE incidentID='$id'");
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

You are executing your insert query twice by using "mysql_query()" twice

you can do:

```
$query="INSERT INTO afgehandelden_incidenten SELECT * FROM incidenten WHERE incidentID='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: please tick it correct after five minutes. It will help me gain reputation

Comment: I'll do that in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

```
if($result=mysql_query($query))
```

will always return true, since it is just an assignment

Comment: Your answer tickled me. I guess you are right, but if I want to check if the function is called right, could I use `if( ( $result=mysql_query($query) ) === true )`? Would that work?

Comment: No you would have to test against $result (the assingment will always return true AFAIK) but you would have to test if `$result` is false or something, `$result` will contain the result from the database query, or `false` on error (i.e. testing for true will generally not work). See php.net/mysql_query

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten the '' marks that inclose the id and also to check whether your query executed or not and whether you have any results use this

```
 row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
 if(!(is_empty($row)){
        $query2=mysql_query("DELETE FROM incidenten WHERE incidentID='$id'");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the lines

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
if($result=mysql_query($query)){
    $query2=mysql_query("DELETE FROM incidenten WHERE incidentID=$id");
}
```

will execute the `$query` twice. So, you should omit the first line, since `if($result=mysql_query($query))` is enough.

Apart from that, checking `$result` on `true` or `false` will just tell you if an error occured or not. What you should do is to check if the `INSERT` statement affected any rows by using `mysql_affected_rows`:

```
if($result=mysql_query($query)){
    if(mysql_affected_rows($connect_mysql) > 0) {
        if($result2=mysql_query("DELETE FROM incidenten WHERE incidentID='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'") {
            /* The query did not return errors */
        }
        else { /* add error handling here */ }
    }
}
else { /* add error handling here */ }
```

Please note:

- I renamed `$query2` to `$result2`, because the variable does not contain a query, but a query result
- Your code is very unsecure because of two reasons:

  - You put a `$_GET` parameter into a query without escaping it. That makes [SQL Injection](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-Injection) as easy as possible! I added the `mysql_real_escape_string` function as an easy way to most likely avoid SQL injection. You should add this function in the `INSERT` statement as well.
  - You use the `mysql_*` functions. These are deprecated and should not be used anymore. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). Use `mysqli` functions or `PDO` istead.